# How can I perform calculations on polynomials in PHP?

Tags: php, math, polynomials

For example, how can I determine the quotient and remainder when something like `x^4 − 3x^2 + 4` is divided by `x − 2`.

I can't figure out how to do this without any library. I am not opposed to using any library but the only one I could find is https://github.com/markrogoyski/math-php and it doesn't support what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

[Synthetic division](https://www.google.com/search?q=polynomial%20synthetic%20division&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS790US790&oq=polynomial%20synthe&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3566j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) was the way I was taught.  Work it out with a piece of paper and pencil.

```
(x^4 -3x^2 + 4)/(x-2) = x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 2 with a remainder of 8.
```

You should be able to figure out how to manipulate arrays of coefficients to get the result you need.

I see three arrays here:

1. The coefficients in the polynomial being divided  (five coefficients - the multiplier for the cubic and linear terms are zero).
2. The coefficients in the dividing polynomial (two coefficients - linear and constant terms).
3. The resulting polynomial.  Initialize it to the coefficients of the polynomial being divided.

Another idea would be to write objects for Monomial and Polynomial.  Build the proper behavior into those objects.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

1. `sudo apt-get install maxima`
2. in PHP `$out = shell_exec("maxima --very-quiet -r 'divide(x^4-3*x^2+4, x-2);'");`

Gives answer in standard output :

> ```
>     3      2
>   [x  + 2 x  + x + 2, 8]
> ```

I've not used polynomials division before, but i suspect that remainder here is given not as a fraction. In that case just append denominator in answer formatting PHP part - in this case 8 / (x-2).